# How can I dynamically populate a query with a List / Array of items in SQL WHERE IN

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a **`List<Long> matchingLongs = new Arraylist();`** that I would like to pass to an SQL statement :

```
WHERE Id IN (matchingLongs);
```

How can I dynamically populate the **`Longs`** into the query?

If I would print to console it should look like :

```
WHERE Id IN (1223, 9834, 3, 924, 88778, 65652165223, 34, 8723738793287);
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should iterate `matchingLongs`, and then add each item to a new string.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getSqlArrayFromList(final List<Long> matchingLongs) {
    StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 0;
    for (Long matchingLong : matchingLongs) {
        if (index == 0) {
            sbuilder.append(matchingLong);
        } else if (index > 0 && index < matchingLongs.size()) {
            sbuilder.append(",").append(matchingLong);
        }
        index++;
    }
    return sbuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about to change one string.

```
if (matchingLongs.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
String str = matchingLongs.toString().replaceAll("[", "(").replaceAll("]", ")");
```